# Python if false, File_read function not activate, if condition problem

Tags: python, if-statement, file-read

I wrote a function can detect USB's path and can keep writing input to file while file path is correct, and read the file out when file incorrect, however **seems my read file function isn't activate**

```
import time
from usb.core import find
from usb.util import get_string
import usb.backend.libusb1
import re
import usb.core
import usb.util
import os
import numpy as np
import os.path
from os import path
import os
import subprocess

def get_USB_path():
    try:
        #use linus call by python
        a = subprocess.check_output(['lsblk'])

        # I split by "\n" cause that in erery line of str_a
        str_a_splited = a.decode().split("\n")

        # USB in linux usually in media file
        USB_info = [s for s in str_a_splited if "/media/" in s]
        found_path = []

        for x in USB_info:
            for s in x.split(" "):
                if "/media/" in s:
                    found_path.append(s)


    except Exception as e:   
        return "error in get_USB_path()" 

    return found_path

path_output = get_USB_path()


def File_write(User_path, user_content):
    try:
        error_info1 = ""
      
        if (path.exists(file_path)) == True:
            file = open(User_path , "a")
            file.write("\n" + user_content)
            file.close()
        else: 
            error_info1 =  "Path incorrect"

    except Exception as e:   
        return "error in File_write()"

    return error_info1


def File_read(input_file_path):
    try:
        with open(input_file_path) as f:
          contents = f.read()

    except Exception as e:   
        return "error in File_read()"

    return contents


print("=  =   =   =   ")
print(path_output)
print(type(path_output))

while True:
    file_path_indexNum = int(input("Enter your desire file path (ex:0,1,2....): "))
    file_name = str(input("Enter your file name (ex:aaa.txt): "))
    file_path = (str(path_output[file_path_indexNum]) +"/" + file_name)
    added_data = str(input("type ur added data : "))  
    
    error_info1  =  File_write(file_path, added_data)
    if (path.exists(file_path)) == True:
        correct_file_path = file_path
    if len(path_output) < file_path_indexNum:
          print("error path, shut down")
        

          break

contents = File_read(correct_file_path)
print(contents)
```

here the error is fine that I simulate the scenario that when file write path is incorrect , then should activate file read, but seems read function is not run yet, here is the output -

```
=  =   =   =   
['/media/joy/DATA2', '/media/joy/DATA', '/media/joy/DATA1']
<class 'list'>
Enter your desire file path (ex:0,1,2....): 0
Enter your file name (ex:aaa.txt): aaa.txt
type ur added data : 65555555
Enter your desire file path (ex:0,1,2....): 0      
Enter your file name (ex:aaa.txt): aaa.txt      
type ur added data : 1313231313
Enter your desire file path (ex:0,1,2....): 6
Enter your file name (ex:aaa.txt): 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joy/fe_dir/damm.py", line 76, in <module>
    file_path = (str(path_output[file_path_indexNum]) +"/" + file_name)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

move `len(path_output) < file_path_indexNum` before into file path, index like 999 ,ore than list can still return [ ] for file path

```
import time
from usb.core import find
from usb.util import get_string
import usb.backend.libusb1
import re
import usb.core
import usb.util
import os
import numpy as np
import os.path
from os import path
import os
import subprocess

def get_USB_path():
    try:
        #use linus call by python
        a = subprocess.check_output(['lsblk'])

        # I split by "\n" cause that in erery line of str_a
        str_a_splited = a.decode().split("\n")

        # USB in linux usually in media file
        USB_info = [s for s in str_a_splited if "/media/" in s]
        found_path = []

        for x in USB_info:
            for s in x.split(" "):
                if "/media/" in s:
                    found_path.append(s)


    except Exception as e:   
        return "error in get_USB_path()" 

    return found_path

path_output = get_USB_path()


def File_write(User_path, user_content):
    try:
        error_info1 = ""
      
        if (path.exists(file_path)) == True:
            file = open(User_path , "a")
            file.write("\n" + user_content)
            file.close()
        else: 
            error_info1 =  "Path incorrect"

    except Exception as e:   
        return "error in File_write()"

    return error_info1


def File_read(input_file_path):
    try:
        with open(input_file_path) as f:
          contents = f.read()

    except Exception as e:   
        return "error in File_read()"

    return contents


print("=  =   =   =   ")
print(path_output)
print(type(path_output))

while True:
    file_path_indexNum = int(input("Enter your desire file path (ex:0,1,2....): "))
    file_name = str(input("Enter your file name (ex:aaa.txt): "))

    if len(path_output) < file_path_indexNum:
        print("error path, shut down")
        break

    file_path = (str(path_output[file_path_indexNum]) +"/" + file_name)
    added_data = str(input("type ur added data : "))  
    
    
    error_info1  =  File_write(file_path, added_data)
    if (path.exists(file_path)) == True:
        correct_file_path = file_path

contents = File_read(correct_file_path)
print(contents)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).